# "To be" before or after?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which of these sentences are correct?

- Do you really want to know what is in my mind?
- Do you really want to know what in my mind is?

I doubted it because people say: `Do you know who I am?` But if you follow up the same structure for the sentences above, it becomes rather weird! (or maybe I'm wrong?)

Comment: In _what is in my mind_, _what_ is the **subject**. In _who I am_, ***I*** is the subject, not _who_. That's why the verb goes at the end there; the _who_ got moved up to the front by question formation.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would you say that _who_ is a subject complement in this case?

Comment: No. That's not how I use the term _complement_. Are you asking about this sentence, or the one it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version is correct. (provided you change *in my mind* to *on my mind*)

> Do you really want to know what is on my mind?

The reason is that *what* is the subject of your secondary clause.

> Something (subject) is on my mind => Do you know what is on my mind?

If it were not the subject, the verb would go to the end.

> My name is Javid (not the subject) => Do you want to know what my name *is*?

Comment: "in my mind" is not incorrect, it just means something else.